# Issue with Vitest and Styled-Components

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, styled-components, vitest

I'm having an issue getting my tests to run with Vitest and Styled Components, it seems like it's not able when rendering components see the entire context of whats happening. I have my component wrapped in a ThemeProvider at the main.tsx level, where I render my . Inside of the App I render the LandingPage, and in the LandingPage I have a useTheme() hook.

Any ideas on what to do?

```
src/App.test.tsx > App > renders GPA in the Works
Error: ThemeProvider: Please make sure your useTheme hook is within a `<ThemeProvider>`
`❯ ce node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:7:8907
❯ Proxy.useTheme node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-
components.browser.esm.js:7:20303
 ❯ HeroSection src/components/sections/landingpage/HeroSection.tsx:131:17
    129| 
    130| function HeroSection() {
    131|   const theme = useTheme();
       |                 ^
    132|   return (
    133|     <HeroContainer>
 ❯ renderWithHooks node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16305:18
 ❯ mountIndeterminateComponent node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20074:13
 ❯ beginWork node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21587:16
 ❯ beginWork$1 node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27426:14
 ❯ performUnitOfWork node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26560:12
 ❯ workLoopSync node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26466:5
 ❯ renderRootSync node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26434:7
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.